# Does semigroup and monoid have to be closed under the binary operation?

Tags: group-theory, semigroups, monoid

As stated in the title, I am wondering whether semigroup and monoid have to be closed under the binary operation. The reason I am asking about this is that in wiki pages of [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup) and [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid), the property of *CLOSED* is not mentioned in the definition, while *CLOSED* is an essential property of group, starting at the beginning of [the definition of group](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Ebrubaker/docs/152/152groups.pdf).

Is wiki wrong about it?

Much appreciation for any help!

Comment: I think that  it is closed follows from associativity: a\*(b\*c) makes only sense if (b\*c) is still in the semigroup

Comment: Both wiki pages explain that by a binary operation (in the definition of a semigrup/monoid) they mean a function $S\times S\to S$.

Comment: @tomasz Ah yes, thanks!

Comment: @miracle173 Thank you!

Comment: @miracle173 You can have non-total structures in which other axioms have a where-exists clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Semigroup* and *monoid* have to be closed under the binary operation. You can conclude it from [wiki's definition of a binary operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation#Terminology) as  "a mapping of the elements of the Cartesian product $S \times  S$ to $S$" and from [wiki's definition of associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#Definition) as
$$(x ∗ y) ∗ z = x ∗ (y ∗ z),\ \forall x, y, z \in S$$
But it is better to state it explicitly that the set S is closed under the operation $*$. Because Wiki defines "an [n-ary operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_(mathematics)#Definition) $\
\omega$ from $X_1\ldots, X_n$ to $Y$ [as] a function $\omega: X_1 \times \ldots \times X_n \to Y$". From this one would conclude that a binary operation from $X_1\, X_2$ to $Y$ must not be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Closure is needed for all of them, but it's often called *totality*. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Group-like_structures) table, which you'll find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup#Generalizations) & [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid#Relation_to_category_theory).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the table, which is very clear and helpful.